# Making relations and foreign keys in a DB

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relationship

I made 3 tables in my database: files, filecontents and users.

The `filecontents'` structure is like:

`id___fileid___filesize___userid___version___path`.

The `files'` is:

```
fileid___filesize___userid___filename___mimetype
```

And `users'`:

```
userid___username___password___email
```

So how should the relations and Foreign key constraints look like so a user can have multi files, each file can have many versions so the fileid should't be a uniqe (I guess). It's like - user `1` has fileid `1`, `2`, `3`. User `2` has different files but their fileid's should start again from `1`.

Comment: Files.fileID, users.userID and filecontents.id all seem like PK's to me and filecontents.fileID, Files.userId, and filecontents.userID,  seem like foreign keys to me.  why wouldn't files.fileID  be unique?  Why do their fileIDs need to start at 1 again?  That's not the nature of a PK.

Comment: Because the logic of my app is every user's files' id is to start from 1

Comment: That sounds more like a display issue not a DB design one.   If you need order add a "files.FileOrder" column and start at one there and increment.  otherwise you are overloading a PK field which could cause you headach if they later want to "Re order" there files.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only have a single auto-increment column in a table. So to do what you want, it should not be a matter of constraints.

You will want to query the largest fileid by using something like `SELECT fileid ORDER BY fileid DESC where userid = x`

Then using that fileid+1 insert the new row. So you will do something like:

```
INSERT INTO xxx SET fileid=(SELECT fileid FROM files ORDER BY fileid DESC where userid=x), userid=x
```

With that said, if fileid is a primary key and not a composite key, it should be an auto-increment. So you should not have a different set of fileid per user.

Answer (score 0):

Relationship between `user` and `file` table is `one to many`. Same goes for the relationship for `user and file_contents` table. Relationship between `file` and `file_contents` table will be `one to one`.

`Files.user_id` will be the `foreign` key from table `users` in which it is `primary` key. `File_contents.user_id` is also a `foreign` key. `Files.fileID, users.userID and file_contents.id` are all `primary` keys in their respective tables.